# Using ts-mockito in angular2 to mock getter

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a service

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private _id: string;
    get id(): string {
        return this._id;
    }
}
```

And a test for a component, where I want to mock this service:

```js
let myServiceMock = mock<MyService>(MyService);
when(myServiceMock.id).thenReturn('mockId');

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        MyModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MyService, useValue: instance(myServiceMock)
        }

    ]
});
```

And when test is running, i get `undefined` as an `id`.

Is it possible to mock getters via mockito?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it is how `TestBed.configureTestingModule` works. It redefines all dependencies which are provided as `useValue`

The solution is using `useFactory`:

```js
let myServiceMock = mock<myServiceMock>(MyService);
when(myServiceMock.id).thenReturn('mockId');

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
        MyModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MyService, useFactory: () => instance(myServiceMock)
        }

    ]
});
```

Comment: That's the weirdest thing I've seen: if you don't mock getters (only functions) then `useValue: instance(myServiceMock)` is enough and works fine, but otherwise `useFactory` is mandatory.